# How to resolve "geo field only has 1 element" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have a geocoded collection that throws an error when I try to query for the number of documents that are geocoded.  Here is my query;

```
Account.exists("locations.coordinates" => false).count
```

Here is the error it throws;

```
failed with error 13068: "exception: geo field only has 1 element :: caused by :: $exists: false"
```

Based on the error message it means some of my coordinates arrays have only one element.  Can someone help me with syntax of how to find accounts with only one element in locations.coordinates?

Note: if I drop the 2d index I can query with no errors and I can rebuild the index, no problem.  I'm looking for way to identify the problem documents.

Comment: I found syntax that will query for number of elements in the coordinates array;

    Account.with_size("locations.coordinates" => 1).count

But, as it turns out there are no documents with only 1 element, so the error message is misleading.

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question.  Are you still looking for help?  If so, please edit the question to reflect what you're trying to figure out.

Comment: I opened a bug report on the misleading error message.  https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9389

Answer (score 0):

In earlier versions of MongoDB, doing this:

```
Account.exists("locations.coordinates" => false).count
```

(or similar) worked. However, in later versions (2.4+) it appears that you want to be searching for 'null'.

```
Account.exists("locations.coordinates" => null).count
```